# toPromise is not a function after importing rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-promise

I want to use Promise operator

First I includeded rxjs:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

then in my component, I used it

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.EJnames= this.dataservice.getResults();
    this.generalinfosservice.getResults("nothing").then(data=>{this.data=data; console.log(data)}); //Log 1
 console.log(this.data); // log 2
  }
```

I got this error

```
ERROR TypeError: this.generalinfosservice.getResults(...).toPromise is not a function
```

I have checked Package.json I have rxjs:

```
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
```

Here's `generalinfosservice.getresults` function

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RmpmService}  from '../../shared/abstract-classes/service'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class GeneralinfosService extends RmpmService {

  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) { }
    public getResults(body) {
        let url;
        let mockUrl
            url = '/obtenirNomenclatures/typeNomenclatures/';
            mockUrl = 'assets/data/group.json';

    return this.post(url, mockUrl, body);
    }
}
```

and post function which is in an abstract class :

```
post( url, mockUrl, body) {
    if( environment.mocked ) {
        return this.httpClient.get( mockUrl ).toPromise().then( data => { return data} );
    } else {
        return this.httpClient.post( url, JSON.stringify( body ) )
            .toPromise()
            .then( data => {
                return data;
            }, ( err: any ) => {
                return this.handleError( err.message );
            } );
    }
}
```

PS: I'm in mocked envirement

Comment: Can you show the type or implementation of generalinfosservice.getResults ?

Comment: Can you show your `this.post` method?

Comment: Your `this.post` method is returning a promise, not an observable

Comment: So I don't need to use another promise in my component , right ?

Comment: Yeah you can get rid of the `toPromise` call in your component as it already is one at that moment. You should be able to see that by logging the response from the call to your console

Comment: I have updated my component code with logs. the **log1** is returning the write data but **log2** is returning an empty array , it should get also all the data because of the `toPromise()` in post method

Comment: It looks like the code isn't formatted correctly. I'm not sure where the log2 is supposed to be running from.

Comment: I'm guessing it is supposed to be the line below the promise. That should be logging your initial value for the data since it is outside of your asynchronous call.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: You'll want to read up on the asynchronous nature of promises to understand fully why your expectation is not correct

Answer (score -1):

You're calling `this.post()` in `getResults()`. This would look for a method in your class (`GeneralInfoService`) called `post()`.

What you actually need to call is `this.httpClient.post()`.

Comment: I realise that I don't need to use toPromise() method in my infosgeneral component  because the post method is already doing it. Can you confim to me that ?

Comment: Whoops didn't realise you had a method called post() declared.

Yes, because post() returns the data itself (not an Observable) you don't need to call toPromise() on it. You will need to await it though (if an async function) or call .then on the result

Answer (score -1):

```js
// Need to import this for my fixes below to work:
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// Your current "post" method.
post( url, mockUrl, body) {
    if( environment.mocked ) {
        // In your promise, you are not returning another promise. You are returning only the "data" value, which doesn't have a ".then()" function associated to it.
        // return this.httpClient.get( mockUrl ).toPromise().then( data => { return data} );
        
        // Here is how you should do it:
        return this.httpClient.get( mockUrl )
            .toPromise()
            .then(( data ) => Observable.of( data ).toPromise());
    } else {
        return this.httpClient.post( url, JSON.stringify( body ) )
            .toPromise()
            .then(
                ( data ) => Observable.of( data ).toPromise(), 
                ( err: any ) => this.handleError( err.message )
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unnecessary to return a promise in the fulfillment method. Simply returning a value will work as it was. The documentation for promises states: "After the invocation of the handler function, if the handler function returns a value, the promise returned by then gets resolved with the returned value as its value" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel => That is true for JavaScript-native promises, but I am not 100% confident that the RxJS library is using them on the back-end, which is why I have it set up the way it is. Yes, it might be unnecessary, but it is guaranteed to return a Promise because the `Observable.of(val).toPromise()` is converting the newly-created Observable to a promise, which is guaranteed to have the `.then()` method.

Comment: According to RxJS documentation, it is guaranteed to behave that way. "Converts an Observable sequence to a ES2015 compliant promise." https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md